# Forms Authentication in WCF after SetAuthCookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

Using `Forms Authentication` to secure my `WCF` service.

After validating the user, I try to set `Forms Authentication Cookie` using the code below:

```
public bool Login(string username, string password)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
                // what should I do here?
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

After the `SetAuthCookie` how exactly should I check if the user is authenticated?
(Whenever I try to access `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, it gives me the value `false`.)

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you returned the cookie in the response in the login WCF service. In your case you can use this code

```
public bool Login(string username, string password)
{
   if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
   {
       //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
       // what should I do here?
       HttpCookie v_Cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie (username,true)
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(v_Cookie);
       return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: still, the next time, when I use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` the value is `false`.

Comment: Okay, I set the cookie. After that, how should I pass this cookie along with every request that I make to the web-service ?

Comment: It depend of web client using.

Comment: @tdelpine: Thanks for the reply. I just use a `console win 32 application`. Can you point me towards the steps?

Comment: if you call the web services with HttpWebRequest, place the recieved cookie authentification in CookieContainer property in each request

Comment: hi @tdelepine what u try to do. the login function should set SetAuthCookie but u comment that line and you return cookie instead. how one can return cookie without creating SetAuthCookie ? may be i do not understand the question well but i like to know what u try to do. please discuss. thanks

Comment: Hi @Thomas with this method you can customize the cookies response and add some properties to it.

Answer (score 0):

set the HttpContext.Current.User in global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest function
in this function,read cookie and create a Principal by cookie value,set it to HttpContext.Current.User